# ¿Puedo cargar un interceptor desde una librería?

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo un interceptor

```
public class ActivityTrackerInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {...  
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {...  
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {...
```

Para cargar el interceptor en el archivo **`persistence.xml`**

```
<properties>  
    ...
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"  
            value="com.demo.ActivityTrackerInterceptor" /> 
</properties>
```

Quiero generar una librería java con el interceptor, pero cuando genero el `jar` no detecta, probé incluyendo la clase en el proyecto y trabaja correctamente. ¿Se puede cargar un interceptor desde un archivo `jar`?

Comment: Sí se puede. Yo tengo mis clases Java y mapeos de Hibernate en unas librerías y adicional a ello tengo un proyecto (jar) donde está la configuración de interceptors para configurarlo por proyecto solo si es necesario. Ahora no te puedo proveer los detalles completos de esto, pero te comunico que realizo esta configuración mediante Spring en el artefacto final, no sé cómo realices todo el wiring de tu proyecto respecto a este tema, tendrías que agregar más información al respecto.

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza, estoy usando EJB y me estoy basando en el siguiente ejemplo https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/ pero llamo el interceptor en el archivo persistence.xml, cuando agrego la clase funciona correctamente, pero si genero la librería no detecta la ruta del archivo persistence.xml

Answer (score 2):

Sí se puede.

Yo tengo mis clases Java y mapeos de Hibernate en unas librerías y adicional a ello tengo un proyecto (jar) donde está la configuración de interceptors para configurarlo por proyecto solo si es necesario.

Realizo esta configuración mediante Spring en el artefacto final.

<sub>[Comentario de Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17659/puedo-cargar-un-interceptor-desde-una-librer%C3%ADa#comment28925_17659) convertido en respuesta en modo wiki de comunidad, para que entre todos lo podamos mejorar.</sub>